# AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random_shuffle'

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When I try to run the code in [machinelearningmastery](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-an-object-detection-model-with-keras/) , I get

> AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'random_shuffle'

And it points at the following

```
from mrcnn.model import MaskRCNN
from mrcnn.config import Config

model = MaskRCNN(mode='training', model_dir='./', config=config)
```

How can one solve this ?

Comment: My TensorFlow version is 2.0.0 whilst in the requirements, it needs 1.3

Comment: That's why. It's renamed to `random.shuffle` in TF2. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/shuffle

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's likely you have Tensorflow 2.0 installed and the code on machine learning mastery has been written on top of tf < 2.0.

You can do either of two things:

- Downgrade your tf to v1.x
- Change tf.random_shuffle to tf.random.shuffle

Also, consider downgrading Keras from v2.3.1 to v2.1.1 (not a must though)

Answer (score 1):

TensorFlow 2.0 has a different API than TensorFlow 1.x, you cannot run software that is made for TensorFlow 1.3 in version 2.0, you need to either downgrade TensorFlow, or find a version of the software that is explicitly made compatible with TensorFlow 2.x

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. And it is resolved by changing tf.random_shuffle to tf.random.shuffle

Comment: where do I change it?

Comment: In model.py file. https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/blob/master/mrcnn/model.py